Designate what thread a controller should run on in spring boot
Does spring boot provide a mechanism by which I can:

declare how many threads should run on the server. I understand this is possible using server.tomcat.threads.max but would like to confirm.
declare which thread a controller should run on? by implication, I should be able to name the threads.

